# Kendo Grid DataSource error handler not firing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Have a Kendo Read Call from JQuery as follows:

```
 var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    error: function (e) {
       if (e.status === "error") {
           this.cancelChanges();
           showToast("Error Occurred", e.xhr.responseText, "exclamation-circle", "red");
           var grid = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid');
           grid.dataSource._data = self.formatData(grid.dataSource.data());
           grid.refresh();
       }
    },
    requestEnd: onRequestEnd,
    transport: {
        read: {
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '/api/user/getall'
        },
        destroy: {
            url: function (data) {
                return "api/user/delete/" + data.RecordKey;
            },
            type: "delete",
            dataType: "json"
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
            return kendo.stringify(data);
        }
    },
```

The server determines user unauthorized and returns the following Content

...

```
        return new ContentResult()
        {
            StatusCode = 401,
            Content = "No Access" 
        };
```

...

The errors blodk in the in the datasource does not fire? Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Still have not figure this out, but getting closer. It seems on the read (fetch) of the grid the onRequestEnd fires but the error block doesn't. So for some reason that function is causing the error block to not fire. Interestingly on the destroy method the error block fires after the onRequestEnd. I will keep digging and have an incident with Telerik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my issue I had an error begin throw in my requestEnd block. Corrected that and error is firing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with the parameterMap definition, specifically when the function is executed on a read operation

```
parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
        if (operation != "read") {
          return kendo.stringify(data);
        }
      }
```

With the above update and a mock 401 response the error event fires as expected - [example](https://dojo.telerik.com/IDubuqul).